# FileSystemException when I try to move erroneous file

Tags: java, javax.xml

I am developing a function that is dedicated to reading XML files. When the reading is correct, the function will move the file to a folder called success, otherwise it will move it to a so-called error. The fact is that, when the file comes well, the function does its job correctly, while when it fails to read it because the file is wrong throws me the following exception:

> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: c:\inbox\TEST.XML ->
> c:\error\TEST.XML: The process cannot access the file because it is
> being used by another process.

This is the code:

```
private void start(){
    //Some stuff
    boolean ok = true;
    try{
         readXml(file.getPath());
    } catch(XmlParserException xmle){
        log.error("Error");
        ok = false;
    } finally {
        moveFiles(ok, file);
    }
}

private void moveFiles(boolean parseOk, File file){
    //Set path with success or error folder
    String path = parseoOk ? (String) mainProperties.get(Constants.SUCCESS)
            : (String) mainProperties.get(Constants.ERROR);

    File fileTo = new File(path + Constants.ROUTE_SLASH + file.getName());

    try {
        Files.move(file.toPath(), fileTo .toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (FileSystemException fse) {
        log.error("In Use");
        log.error(fse.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("IOERROR");
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void readXml(String rutaFichero) throws XmlParserException{
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = initializeDocumentBuilder();
    try {
        File archivo = new File(rutaFichero);
        Document documento = documentBuilder.parse(archivo); //Fails here
        //Do some stuff
    } catch(XPathExpressionException | DOMException | SAXException | IOException | ParseException e1){
        throw new XmlParserException("Error when parsing XML: " + e1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you close the xml file you just opened if an error occurs?

Comment: Try using ```InputStream```  in a try-with-resources block.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca DocumentBuilder try to parse it and when it can't function moveFiles try to move and it launches the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you have any un-closed file read/write operations for the xml file. If you haven't, maybe `documentBuilder.parse(archivo)` isn't closing streams it opens. You may be able to verify this with switch to `FileInputStream`:

```
File archivo = new File(rutaFichero);
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(archivo)) {
    Document documento = documentBuilder.parse(in);
    // ...
} catch(XPathExpressionException | DOMException | SAXException | IOException | ParseException e1){
    throw new XmlParserException("Error when parsing XML: " + e1);
}
```

**UPDATE**

A not-closed `File` after XML parse issue appears in JDK bug database a few times for SAX + DOM, see the `DocumentBuilder.parse(File)` issue  [JDK-8151585](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8151585). The code I've proposed above is a good workaround to this bug.